# Supporting Enum in EF 5 with .Net 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, enum

I'm currently working through [Getting Started with EF5 using MVC 4](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4) in Visual Studio 2010 (.NET 4.0) to learn about how to use ASP.NET and Entity Framework. During the beginning of the tutorial I ran into an issue with enum support when creating a database with Code First Migrations. For reasons unknown I have to work in this environment and create my own support for enums so I decided to make the property `int` instead then I would convert it to Enum when I want to display it like so:

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Html;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace ContosoUniversity.Extensions
{
    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static String DisplayAsEnum<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> cHtml,
                                                           Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> cExpression,
                                                           Type cType,
                                                           String strDisplay = "Unknown")
        {
            try
            {
                if (cType.IsEnum)
                {
                    object cResult = cExpression.Compile().DynamicInvoke(cHtml.ViewData.Model);

                    if (cResult != null)
                    {
                        strDisplay = Enum.ToObject(cType, cResult).ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception cExc)
            {
                strDisplay = cExc.ToString();
            }

            return (strDisplay);
        }
    }
}
```

In my razor cshtml file I display it to the webpage with this call:

```
@Html.DisplayAsEnum(modelItem => item.Grade, typeof(Grade), "No Grade")
```

I have a feeling that this is not the "professional" or "right" way of handling the lack of enum support so I was wondering if there is anyway to improve this function or is there a better way of handling enumerations in EF 5 with .Net 4.0 support?

I was shown a Stack Overflow question that provides me with a better solution to handling the enum support. It is very helpful and I am using it at the moment, but since I do like the function that I made, is it possible to improve it?

Comment: This [StackOverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15818622/how-to-map-an-enum-property-in-entity-framework-4) should be right up your alley. In my opinion the accepted answer is a cleaner solution.

Comment: @GregBurghardt It looks like I should of paid more attention to StackOverflow before posting my question lol. That did work for me, and without needed to re-update the database. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ideally you won't want to change the `strDisplay`, so we should probably take it out of the parameter list and make it a constant inside the method and then just return in each of the 3 circumstances.

```
var display = "Unknown";

try
{
    if (cType.IsEnum)
    {
        object cResult = cExpression.Compile().DynamicInvoke(cHtml.ViewData.Model);

        if (cResult != null)
        {
            return Enum.ToObject(cType, cResult).ToString();
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception cExc)
{
    return cExc.ToString();
}

return display;
```

this seems weird to me that we are using the variable (*whatever you choose to name it*)  only once, I would probably in this circumstance (since we aren't allowing it to be changed)  just return the string `Unknown` like this

```
try
{
    if (cType.IsEnum)
    {
        object cResult = cExpression.Compile().DynamicInvoke(cHtml.ViewData.Model);

        if (cResult != null)
        {
            return Enum.ToObject(cType, cResult).ToString();
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception cExc)
{
    return cExc.ToString();
}

return "Unknown";
```

Comment: I don't know why the other answer got deleted but I do like this answer. It does make sense to me to not change `strDisplay`. I don't know what I was thinking at the time lol. Thanks for the answer!